# Error when switching scenes React native router flux

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am currently working on a react native app using react native router flux and am getting an error message whenever switching scenes.

```
[Mon Jul 20 2020 10:14:47.942]  ERROR    currentlyFocusedField is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use currentlyFocusedInput 
Transitioner@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:115890:36
StackView@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:111907:36
Navigator@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:102007:38
KeyboardAwareNavigator@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:106488:38
NavigationContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:105963:38
App@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:99452:36
Router@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:99597:30
App
RCTView
RCTView
AppContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:67802:22
```

I cant seem to find any info about this on google. It doesn't seem to be causing any issues with the app at the moment but would like to try and find out what is causing this incase it does down the line.

Thanks

Comment: What's your [rnrf](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux#react-native-router-v4x------) version and react-navigation version? rnrf only support react-navigation v4.x! if you are using v5 may cause problem.

Comment: @react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

I think, you use the new version of react-native 0.63.1.
On the new version of *react-native-router-flux*, this issue will solved. Currently, I ignore this issue.

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['currentlyFocusedField is deprecated']);
```

Comment: I tried to use this but the error message still shows whenever i switch scenes